# NARX Neural Network

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Всем привет !
Ребята, пытаюсь научить нейронку NARX на Python, пример кода и, собственно, саму реализацию взял отсюда http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/recurrent.html
Однако ничерта не получается, как я ни менял данные, скрытые слои и тд
Может я что-то не так понял в алгоритме, может не так задал данные. 
В общем прикрепляю ссылку на код и просьбу о помощи !
https://github.com/DimaVilda/NARX